# HDInsight powershell job submission has no way to define custom libjar with streaming C# job

Tags: powershell, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming, azure-hdinsight

I have C# jobs running on hadoop cluster hosted by Microsoft Azure HDInsight services.
I had to use the hadoop command line directly in my hdinsight server in order to use my custom Java input format :

**call bin\hadoop jar lib\hadoop-streaming.jar -D "mapred.max.split.size=33554432" -libjars "../mycustom-hadoop-streaming.jar" -inputformat "mycustom.hadoop.CombinedInputFormat"**
...(I cut the rest of the command)

Now I am trying to do same with Job submission through powershell command line (remote job submission from another azure machine) :

**$jobDefinition = New-AzureHDInsightStreamingMapReduceJobDefinition -Defines @{ "mapred.max.split.size"="33554432", "mapred.input.format.class"="mycustom.hadoop.CombinedInputFormat" }**
... (I cut the rest of the command)

But where is the way to define -libjars with powershell command line ?
It seems that Microsoft didn't think about that capability :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn527638.aspx

Does anybody tried to perform that or have a workaround to define libjars with HDInsight streaming job submission ?

Comment: I didn't understand from the answer, did you find a work around to submit the job with powershell using libjars ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may know, HDInsight PowerShell and .Net SDK uses WebHcat/Templeton REST API and I believe, the reason New-AzureHDInsightStreamingMapReduceJobDefinition doesn't have -libjars as a paremeter is, Templeton REST API does not have that or support that, as shown in the apache templeton doc here-
http://people.apache.org/~thejas/templeton_doc_latest/mapreducestreaming.html

On the other hand, Templeton REST API for MapReduce/JAR supports libjars
http://people.apache.org/~thejas/templeton_doc_latest/mapreducejar.html

and accordingly, corresponding HDInsight cmdlet New-AzureHDInsightMapReduceJobDefinition has a -Libjars parameter.

I hope it helps to explain!

Azim(MSFT)

Comment: Thanks Azim, it answers my question.